# RecordType DeveloperName dynamically using scehma.getGlobalDescribe

Tags: apex, schema

Hi I need to access recordtype details for case Object using DeveloperName. Is there any way I can get complete record type details using `schema.getGlobalDescribe` method? Or is there any other way to fetch this **without using SOQL**.

I wrote a piece of code

```
System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName());
```

This call doesn't give DeveloperName. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need the Developer Name?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use query and create Map. There is no way to get DeveloperName form Schema class...

Comment: Maybe any examples / docs?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to find any direct note that Schema CAN'T return DeveloperName. And I see it as pointless to link documentation about Schema class which @Phaniraj3107 obviously know. My answer is based on my experience only.

Comment: @ArturKępczyński I think what was meant was to post an example of the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is a case submitted to Salesforce related to this topic. To sum up you cannot do it without SOQL. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K9zoAAC