# Getting record type id by developer name without making query

Tags: apex, record-type

We have below describe call to get the record type id by name.

```
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME_NOT_DEVELOPER_NAME').getRecordTypeId();
```

This gives the id of the record but this logic is based on label of the record type instead of developer name. That means if we change the Label of record type then any code using such mechanism will break.

I know we can make a query to get the record type id by developer name but that will cost me a SOQL which I don't want to.

Is there any describe call to get the record type id by developer name without making the SOQL?

Comment: Why it was marked as a duplicate? This is completely opposite question. 
Previous one is about 'Getting Developer Name By Id'
This on is about 'Getting ID by Name'

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the APIs are not supporting this, but there is an Idea for exactly this use case: [Get RecordTypeInfos by API name method](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K9zoAAC)

Some related questions:

- [Get Record Type Developer Name without SOQL Query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77520/get-record-type-developer-name-without-soql-query)
- [RecordType DeveloperName dynamically using scehma.getGlobalDescribe](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69121/recordtype-developername-dynamically-using-scehma-getglobaldescribe)
- [What would be the best approach to get the recordtype id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id)

Comment: This is under review, so at least there's Hope for the future.

Comment: I thought I saw a tweet that there would be some progress in an upcoming release, but I can't recall exactly what it said.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, someone leaked a pic of the Apex Code road map. Forward-Looking Statement and all that, but here's hoping.

Comment: Thank you. I think then we need to wait for salesforce to provide such methods.

Comment: Now you can use getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName() which was made available in Summer'18.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_methods

Comment: Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Customer_Account').getRecordTypeId();
System.debug('RecordTypeId based on Developer Name ---> '+idRecordId);